# How can I get picklist values from Custom Metadata Type?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, vs-code, custom-metadata

I'm building LWC component and I have custom metadata type that has picklist field with 70 values.

**I need to display them as options in dual-list-box in LWC.**

Is there any imports that I can use to read the values directly or should I use @wire to read the picklist values from apex and send back to JS the values to display and if so, how?

Thank you.

**EDIT 1:**

I used the first suggestion, created a apex method and called it with @wire.

```
            String elementValue;
            String elementLabel;
            List<String> sessionOptions = new List<String>();
            
            Schema.DescribeFieldResult objFieldDescribe = Piwik_Pro_Integration_Settings__mdt.Piwik_Pro_Fields_Session__c.getDescribe();
            List<Schema.PicklistEntry> lstPickListValues = objFieldDescribe.getPickListValues();
            
            for (Schema.PicklistEntry objPickList : lstPickListValues) {
                elementLabel = objPickList.getLabel();
                sessionOptions.add(elementLabel);
            }
            // system.debug(apiNamesList);
            return sessionOptions;
```

VS Code JS call:

```
@wire(getOptions, { dataType: 'dataType'})
dualListBoxOption;
```

VS dual list box:

```
<lightning-dual-listbox name="dimensions"
                        label="Select Dimensions"
                        source-label="Available"
                        selected-label="Selected"
                        field-level-help="Select your preferred dimensions:"
                        options={dualListBoxOption}
                        onchange={selectedDimensionsSet}>
</lightning-dual-listbox>
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
    import { LightningElement, track, wire, api} from 'lwc';
    import getPicklistValues from '@salesforce/apex/PiwikHttpCallout.getPicklistValues';

@wire(getPicklistValues,{dataType: '$dataType'})pickListValues({data,error}){
        if(data){
            this.showPickList = true;
            data.forEach(i => {
                this.options.push({label:i,value:i});
            });
            // console.log(this.options);
        }
    };

<lightning-dual-listbox 
        if:true={showPickList} 
        name="dimensions" 
        label="Select Dimensions" 
        source-label="Available"
        selected-label="Selected" 
        field-level-help="Select your preferred dimensions" 
        options={options}>
    </lightning-dual-listbox>
```

APEX:

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<String> getPicklistValues(String dataType){
        List<String> pickListValues  = new List<String>();
        if(dataType=='Sessions'){
            Schema.DescribeFieldResult pickList = Metadata__mdt.Metadata1__c.getDescribe();
            for( Schema.PicklistEntry pickVal : pickList.getPicklistValues()){
                pickListValues .add(pickVal.getLabel());
            }   
            return pickListValues;
        }
        else if(dataType=='Events'){
            Schema.DescribeFieldResult pickList = Metadata__mdt.Metadata__c.getDescribe();
            for( Schema.PicklistEntry pickVal : pickList.getPicklistValues()){
                pickListValues .add(pickVal.getLabel());
            }   
            return pickListValues;
        }
        else return null;
    }
```

[image: Error]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTMl :

```
<template>
    <lightning-dual-listbox if:true={showPickList} name="dimensions" label="Select Dimensions" source-label="Available"
        selected-label="Selected" field-level-help="Select your preferred dimensions:" options={options}>
    </lightning-dual-listbox>
</template>
```

JS :

```
import { LightningElement,track, wire, api } from 'lwc';
import getPicklistValues from '@salesforce/apex/customApexClass.getPicklistValues';

export default class OpportunityLwc extends LightningElement {
    @track options = [];
    showPickList = false;
    @wire(getPicklistValues)pickListValues({data,error}){
        if(data){
            this.showPickList = true;
            data.forEach(i => {
                this.options.push({label:i,value:i});
            });
            console.log(this.options);
        }
    };
}
```

Apex :

```
public with sharing class customApexClass {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<String> getPicklistValues(){
        List<String> pickListValues = new List<String>();
        Schema.DescribeFieldResult pickList = metadata__mdt.Type__c.getDescribe();
        for( Schema.PicklistEntry pickVal : pickList.getPicklistValues()){
            pickListValues.add(pickVal.getValue());
        }   
        return pickListValues;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! It works. One more question if I may. How can I send String variable to the @wire js call?

Comment: @wire(getPicklistValues,{dataType : '$variableName'})pickListValues({data,error})

If its work please mark this as best answer

Comment: I get -  LWC1007:  Leading decorators must be attached to a class declaration error. What might it be?

Comment: can you show me your js code

Comment: I've edited my post - Edit 2. The error is on line: @wire(getPicklistValues,{dataType: '$dataType'})pickListValues({data,error}){

Comment: define dataType variable with default value line "Sessions" or "Events" in js.
currently your variable is undefined

Comment: Still, the same 3 errors. 1)  Leading decorators must be attached to a class declaration. (38:52) 2) Declaration expected. 3) ';' expected.

Answer (score 2):

1. With Apex

you can use this apex script

```
Schema.DescribeFieldResult pickList = {MetaData_Api_Name}.{Picklist_Api_Name}.getDescribe();
for( Schema.PicklistEntry pickVal : pickList.getPicklistValues()){
    System.debug(pickVal.getLabel()+' '+ pickVal.getValue());
}
```

return list of string or wrapper.
get it from wire method in js.

2. Without Apex

   @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: OBJECT_NAME })
   objectInfo;

   @wire(getPicklistValues, {
   recordTypeId: '$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId',
   fieldApiName: TYPE_FIELD
   }) statusValues;

NOTE : Import proper values in js
Like

> import OBJECT_NAME from '@salesforce/schema/Object__c';
> import TYPE_FIELD from
> '@salesforce/schema/Object__c.Field__c';

Comment: I think 2 approach will not work because metadata not having recordtypeId.

Comment: I tried the first suggestion, but it doesn't work - still, the picklist values are not displayed as options in the dual list box? I've edited the post for detailed code of @wire call, apex method and dua list box code.